# Postman: "Import From Link" does not work

Tags: postman

In `Postman`, I did these: Import > Import From Link, and then I entered a URL

```
https://www.getpostman.com/collections/1c6c3d5cfe3b12978a5f
```

And then I hit "Import".  But then nothing happened.  There were no error messages.  The click simply gave no response/action from the UI.

Did I miss something?

( The above procedures and link were suggested from this [blog article](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/10/28/using-csv-and-json-files-in-the-postman-collection-runner/) from Postman offical site)

I was using Postman v6.6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Postman to hit the same URL you'll see this:

[image: Collection not found]

***Error: Collection not found.***

It's probably a deleted collection.

Checking the logs, I can see that there's an error that the resource couldn't be found but yeah the UI apparently doesn't give you any feedback regarding this which can be reported.

You can report the issue on the [public issue tracker](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues)

Answer (score 1):

Import worked after restarting the postman ,
version : Version 7.6.0 (7.6.0)